# "where" queries using HQL-like syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm a fan of Hibernate's HQL syntax, that lets me form queries that traverse model relationships, like:

```
from Book book where book.publisher.lastName = 'jones'
from Book book where book.chapters.length = 2
```

Is there an ActiveRecord syntax for traversing models like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest you're going with to get with ARel is:

```
Book.joins(:publisher).where('publishers.lastName = ?', 'Jones')
```

or

```
Book.where(:publisher_id => Publisher.where(:last_name => 'Jones'))
```

(which is probably less efficient, as it will being hitting the database twice instead of once)

and

```
Book.joins(:chapters).group('books.id').having('count(chapters) = ?', 2)
```

Which I admit is a bit less readable.

There are some gems, [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) is the one that comes to mind, which let you change up your query syntax in various ways - it's possible one of them will feel closer to what you want to use.